# Interacting with filesystem

Tags: python

The question is:
Have file named count_lines which takes two arguments: the first is a path to an input file to read, the second is the path to an output file to write
It returns True on success, False if something went wrong (i.e an error occurred)
The function will count the number of lines in the file at the first argument, and write this number to a file at the second argument.

This is what I have:

```
def count_files(inpet_txt, outpet_txt):
    count_files = open(inpet_txt)
    txt = count_files.read()
    count_files.close()
    count_files = open(outpet_txt)
    txt = count_files.write()

    True
    print("success")
    False
    print("error")

    return False
```

It wants me to return false. 
I've fixed the errors it told me I had and now its saying that i have a name error of count_line? 
Anyways - please help correct my code if it is wrong! Thank you!

Comment: `open(outpet_txt)` the default mode for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is "r" (for reading). If you want to open a file for writing, you need to call: `open(outpet_txt, "w")`

Comment: Don't name variables the same as the name of the function (`count_files`)

Comment: Consider revising your problem statement (hopefully, not homework) a bit. You have a function that takes two arguments (not a file that takes 2 args). Your function doesn't count lines (hint: There's a `while` loop missing) and there you don't check for `open()`'s error (when you should return `False`).

Comment: You need to conditionally return `True` of `False`. Hint: an `if` statement will probably be required.

Comment: Another hint: Look in the Python documentation for a function called `lines()`. http://doc.python.org/ (BTW: Which Python version are you using/learning? 2 or 3?)

Comment: thanks guys! i am using python 3

Comment: would you say while open(jdh, "r") & open(kjdhf, "w") if txt = hfdslfh, count = jhdhsd true?

Comment: The general idiom for working with files is `with open('something', 'r') as f` or `with open('output', 'w') as w:` (sorry, but comments aren't a great way to illustrate code snippets.)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

def cnt(pth1, pth2):
    try:
        with Path(pth1).open() as p1:
            with Path(pth2).open('w') as p2:
                c = 0
                for i in p1.open():
                    c +=1
                p2.write(c)
        return True
    except Exception:
        pass
    return False
```